# How to make get request using Alamofire when there is query parameters present in the url?

Tags: swift, url, parameters, get, alamofire

I am trying to make Get request using Alamofire. The url has query parameter in it - "api_key". I tried to add it as a parameter but the response is not generated.

The error says- "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

The operation couldn’t be completed."

Need help in calling this get request correctly.

Networking Service -

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

typealias Handler = (Swift.Result<Any?, APIErrors>) -> Void

enum APIErrors: Error {
    case custom(message: String)
}

class NetworkingService {
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkingService()
    
    func nowPlayingMethod(completionHandler: @escaping Handler) {
        let parameter: Parameters  = [
            "api_key": "some value",
        ]
        
        AF.request("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing", method: .get, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).response { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(NowPlaying.self, from: data!)
                    print(json)
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 || response.response?.statusCode == 201 {
                        completionHandler(.success(json))
                    }else {
                        completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please check your network connectivity")))
                    }
                }catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please try again")))
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please try again")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this method from viewDidload -

```
        NetworkingService.sharedInstance.nowPlayingMethod { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let json):
                print(json as AnyObject)

//                let type = (json as! NowPlaying).type
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)` & maybe `if let data = response.data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print("Response string:: \(str)}`. What are the output for that? And there are two "print(error.localizedDescription)", which one prints in console?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with the parameter? Sounds to me more likely your JSON parsing failed, and that's possibly because the response is not the JSON you expect (e.g. wrong structure, or json with error, or not json at all)

Comment: @thiscommunityistoxic The model was incorrect hence the error. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Larme
 The model was incorrect hence the error. Thank you for your input.